# Get Enum type by mapping Enum value always complain null issue Android Kotlin

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, enums

I have enum class and I am mapping by value, when I am return Enum value it always complain about null issue.

**ConversationStatus.kt**

```
enum class ConversationStatus(val status: String) {
    OPEN("open"),
    CLOSED("closed");

    companion object {
        private val mapByStatus = values().associateBy(ConversationStatus::status)
        fun fromType(status: String): ConversationStatus {
            return mapByStatus[status]
        }
    }
}
```

This always complain this issue. How can I fix this? Any recommendation for that. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 3 possible ways to go to.
Android Studio is often good at suggested fixes as you can see in the screenshot. It suggests to change the return type to `ConversationStatus?` which means it might return null. It will become this then:

```
companion object {
    private val mapByStatus = values().associateBy(ConversationStatus::status)
    fun fromType(status: String): ConversationStatus? {
        return mapByStatus[status]
    }
}
```

Another way is to tell the compiler that you ensure it will always not be null by adding `!!` to the return statement. Like this:

```
companion object {
    private val mapByStatus = values().associateBy(ConversationStatus::status)
    fun fromType(status: String): ConversationStatus {
        return mapByStatus[status]!!
    }
}
```

This will cause a crash though if you call the function with a status that's not `"open"` or `"closed"`

Alternatively you could provide a fall back value. With this I mean that it returns a default value in case you call the function with a string that's not `"open"` or `"closed"`. If you want that to be `OPEN` you could do like this:

```
companion object {
    private val mapByStatus = values().associateBy(ConversationStatus::status)
    fun fromType(status: String): ConversationStatus {
        return mapByStatus[status] ?: OPEN
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `!!` it is better to use [`getValue`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html) function

Comment: @IR42 why is that? I guess it's subjective but I don't see why that would be any better. The only difference is that the Exception thrown will be different when called with a non-valid string. Either way they would cause a crash

Comment: @IvoBeckers great answer, I'll go with 3 approach. Thanks